# Navigating from a DialogFragment to a Fragment removes DialogFragment from back stack - Android Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation

The flow is `FragmentA` -> `DialogFragment` -> `FragmentB`. Press back button from `FragmentB` and the app skips `DialogFragment` and goes to `FragmentA`.

I am trying to understand if this is the expected behavior or it is a bug. If that is the design, how can I possibly ensure pressing back goes to the dialog fragment instead of back to `FragmentA`

Comment: This happens because the Dialog destintation implements FloatingWindow interface that is always popped from the back stack when navigating from it. Check the source code